# Checking RAM on a Cisco device

Tags: router, memory, switch

When you do the "show version" command on a Cisco networking device you get some basic software and hardware information, including the amount of RAM which is shown like this: http://gyazo.com/52bbfa7c6742558daae799d6189ccd6c

What I don't get is why it says "61440K/4088K bytes of memory", **why are there two values and why are they different?**

Comment: its likely ( total memory available / memory used )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/fundamentals/command/reference/cf_book/cf_s4.html#wp1499591) it is displaying free memory / used memory which makes sense since the two values add up to 64MB which is a common amount for similiar devices.

Comment: Makes sense!_______